# iPhone sdk - UIImageView overlap issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView as shown in the attached image. I use a UIImageView in the custom cell of the UITableView and I rotate to some degrees. The images in the UIImageView are fit according to their size. The problem is, some of the images are overlapped on the view of next cell. Though the UIImageView exceeds the boundary of the cell, I do not want the image to be overlapped. Someone help me to come out of this problem. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the property **`masksToBounds: YES`** for the `UIImageView`.

Comment: Isn't it `clipsToBounds`? Or, you mean `imageView.layer.masksToBounds`?

Comment: And I think you should do `cell.clipsToBounds`, not `imageView.clipsToBounds`. Correct?